# Factorizing Odd Prime Case of FLT using Roots of Unity

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity

I am studying a fake proof of FLT which assumes $\mathbb Q\left[\zeta_p \right]$ is a UFD (that is, that the rationals with the pth root of unity is a UFD). We have covered the proofs for n=2, 3, and 4. The graduate student I am studying under tasked me with proving the following, which will be used in our fake proof:

$$x^p+y^p=\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}\left(x\zeta^{i}_p + y\zeta^{p-i}_p\right),\label{1}\tag{1}$$

for p, an odd prime. I am not quite sure how to go about this. We've already proven that

$$x^p+y^p=\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}\left(x + y\zeta^k_p\right),\label{2}\tag{2}$$

and I understand why this formula results from the definition of $\zeta_p$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598447/how-to-prove-xpyp-displaystyle-prod-k-0p-1-x-xi-pky)).

I've explored the expansion of \eqref{1}, as well as tried to look at perhaps a proof by induction or some method of rewriting \eqref{1} in terms of \eqref{2}, but to no avail. Any hints that might help prove the first statement would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a "fake" proof, it's a fake proof. You could also say it's a "proof".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}\left(x\zeta^{i}_p + y\zeta^{p-i}_p\right) = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1}\zeta_p^i \cdot \prod_{i=0}^{p-1}\left(x+ y\zeta^{p-2i}_p\right)$$ Then observe that when $i$ varies from $0$ to $p-1$, the numbers $\zeta_p^{p-2i}$ are a permutation of the numbers $\zeta_p^i$.